# What kinds of services can I get at the College?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed that certain members of the College seem to specialize in specific kinds of services. One person only sells Illusion spells, another offers enchanting, etc.

What are all the services offered in the College, and which members offer those services?

Comment: I'm especially interested in finding some Destruction spells at the moment. The starting spells are beginning to get a bit weak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Phinis Gestor** sells conjuring spells and trains

**Faradala** sells destruction spells and trains

**Colette Marence** is for restoration and trains

**Drevis Neloren** is for Illusion and trains

**Sergius Turrianus** is for enchanting and trains

**Tolfdir** is for Alteration and trains